# solving differential equation $y''(x) + x^2 y'(x) + (2 x + 1) y(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem solving differential equation below.

$$y''+x^2y'+(2x+1)y=0$$

How can I solve this equation?
I tried to use my textbook to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to have enough information I need.

Comment: Just something I noticed - if you let $u=x^2$, then $y''+uy'+u'y+y=0$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: I tried to solve it using DSolve in MMA. However, it doesn't seem to have a nice solution. At least, not one that MMA could find.

Comment: Can you/have you tried developing a series solution?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this relates to [Heun's Triconfluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E4).